# Adding a Foreign Key MySQSL Workbench MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to add a foreign key at my table, the column called `brand_agricultural_machine_id`
[image]

And at Foreign Key option
[image]

But when I click at `Apply`

```
ALTER TABLE `autoparanaiba`.`model_agricultural_machine` 
ADD COLUMN `brand_agricultural_machine_id` TINYINT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AFTER `description`,
ADD INDEX `fk_model_gricultural_machine_brand_agricultural_machine1_idx` (`brand_agricultural_machine_id` ASC) VISIBLE;
;
ALTER TABLE `autoparanaiba`.`model_agricultural_machine` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_model_gricultural_machine_brand_agricultural_machine1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`brand_agricultural_machine_id`)
  REFERENCES `autoparanaiba`.`brand_agricultural_machine` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Appear this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the script where has about index `ASC VISIBLE`, I deleted this at the script and I added, and work out.